# SUMIF the row can be found on another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, sumifs, google-query-language

In my head this seems very simple but I for some reason I can't figure it out.

I have a list of lumber at a job site and I am wanting to add all the boards together that are the same size and length. I want to search "Lumber List w/o Duplicates" tab and see how many boards I have in total of that exact size.

For example I would think the formula would be: `=SUMIF(A1:D1,'Lumber List'!A:D,'Lumber List'!E:E)`

Here is the spreadsheet I am working on. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ocGFAeZDlsgaBR5K5gAisymBNaWQxrVDNnsyvtBcbB4/edit?usp=sharing

Any help would be great, and thank you so much in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY('Lumber List'!A:E, 
 "select A,B,C,D,sum(E) 
  where A is not null 
  group by A,B,C,D 
  order by sum(E) desc 
  label sum(E)''")
```